# How do I print UTF-8 from c++ console application on Windows

Tags: c++, utf-8, console-application

For a C++ console application compiled with Visual Studio 2008 on  English Windows (XP,Vista or 7). Is it possible to print out to the console and correctly display UTF-8 encoded Japanese using cout or wcout?

Comment: There's an interesting thread at cplusplus.com : UTF-8 in command prompt (console) http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/9797/

Comment: **Newcomers:** [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40337240/3258851) on using unicode - and check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26479960/3258851) on changing the console font.

Answer (score 20):

This should work:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma execution_character_set( "utf-8" )

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP( 65001 );
    printf( "Testing unicode -- English -- Ελληνικά -- Español -- Русский. aäbcdefghijklmnoöpqrsßtuüvwxyz\n" );
}
```

Don't know if it affects anything, but source file is saved as **Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001** at **FILE** -> **Advanced Save Options ...**.

**Project** -> **Properties** -> **Configuration Properties** -> **General** -> **Character Set** is set to **Use Unicode Character Set**.

Some say you need to change console font to *Lucida Console*, but on my side it is displayed with both *Consolas* and *Lucida Console*.

Comment: Default cmd console are in codepage 850. This solution doesn't seem to work on that default settings. Did you change something else?

Comment: @Sandburg I don't remember changing anything else, but suggest it might be something to do with my Windows being localized for Russian.

Answer (score 10):

The Windows console uses the [OEM code page](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/29/457483.aspx) by default to display output.

To change the code page to Unicode enter **`chcp 65001`** in the console, or try to change the code page programmatically with [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682064.aspx).

Note that you probably have to change the font of the console to one that has glyphs in the unicode range.

Comment: Be aware that there are many bugs with UTF-8 as codepage. Most are WONTFIX.

Answer (score 8):

[Here's an article from MVP Michael Kaplan](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx) on how to correctly output UTF-16 through the console. You could convert your UTF-8 to UTF-16 and output that.

Comment: One observation: Michael Kaplan is not an MVP. I don't know if he ever was. He's been a Microsoft employee for ages (Microsoft employees are not eligible for the MVP program).

Comment: This link brings to _Resource Not Found_.

Comment: As of 2016-08-09, the link redirects to http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.html but there is material present (presumably what was originally at siao2.com).

Comment: Permalink: https://web.archive.org/web/20131118014725/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I've never actually tried setting the console code-page to UTF8 (not sure why it wouldn't work... the console can handle other multi-byte code-pages just fine), but there are a couple of functions to look up:  SetConsoleCP and SetConsoleOutputCP.

You'll probably also need to make sure you're using a console font that is capable of displaying your characters.  There's the [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686200(VS.85).aspx) function, but it's only available on Vista and above.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

On app start console set to default OEM437 CP.
I was trying to output Unicode text to stdout, where console was switch to UTF8 translation _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT); and still had no luck on the screen even with Lucida TT font.
If console was redirected to file, correct UTF8 file were created.

Finally I was lucky. I have added single line "info.FontFamily   = FF_DONTCARE;" and it is working now.
Hope this help for you.

```
void SetLucidaFont()
{
    HANDLE StdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX));
    info.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);              // prevents err=87 below
    if (GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(StdOut, FALSE, &info))
    {
        info.FontFamily   = FF_DONTCARE;
        info.dwFontSize.X = 0;  // leave X as zero
        info.dwFontSize.Y = 14;
        info.FontWeight   = 400;
        _tcscpy_s(info.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
        if (SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(StdOut, FALSE, &info))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `system` call:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    system("chcp 65001");
    printf("%s\n", "中文");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the console, enter `chcp 65001` to change the code page to that of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Just for additional information:

'ANSI' refers to windows-125x, used for win32 applications while 'OEM' refers to the code page used by console/MS-DOS applications.
Current active code-pages can be retrieved with functions GetOEMCP() and GetACP().

In order to output something correctly to the console, you should:

1. ensure the current OEM code page supports the characters you want to output
   (if necessary, use SetConsoleOutputCP to set it properly)
2. convert the string from current ANSI code (win32) to the console OEM code page

Here are some utilities for doing so:

```
// Convert a UTF-16 string (16-bit) to an OEM string (8-bit) 
#define UNICODEtoOEM(str)   WCHARtoCHAR(str, CP_OEMCP)

// Convert an OEM string (8-bit) to a UTF-16 string (16-bit) 
#define OEMtoUNICODE(str)   CHARtoWCHAR(str, CP_OEMCP)

// Convert an ANSI string (8-bit) to a UTF-16 string (16-bit) 
#define ANSItoUNICODE(str)  CHARtoWCHAR(str, CP_ACP)

// Convert a UTF-16 string (16-bit) to an ANSI string (8-bit)
#define UNICODEtoANSI(str)  WCHARtoCHAR(str, CP_ACP)


/* Convert a single/multi-byte string to a UTF-16 string (16-bit).
 We take advantage of the MultiByteToWideChar function that allows to specify the charset of the input string.
*/
LPWSTR CHARtoWCHAR(LPSTR str, UINT codePage) {
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, str, len, NULL, 0);
    LPWSTR wstr = (LPWSTR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(WCHAR) * size_needed);
    MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, str, len, wstr, size_needed);
    return wstr;
}


/* Convert a UTF-16 string (16-bit) to a single/multi-byte string.
 We take advantage of the WideCharToMultiByte function that allows to specify the charset of the output string.
*/
LPSTR WCHARtoCHAR(LPWSTR wstr, UINT codePage) {
    size_t len = wcslen(wstr) + 1;
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, wstr, len, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    LPSTR str = (LPSTR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(CHAR) * size_needed );
    WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, wstr, len, str, size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone need to read UTF-8 from file and print to console can try `wifstream`, even in visual studio debugger shows UTF-8 words correctly (I'm processing traditional chinese), from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring readFile(const char* filename)
{
    std::wifstream wif(filename);
    wif.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}
 
//  usage
std::wstring wstr2;
wstr2 = readFile("C:\\yourUtf8File.txt");
wcout << wstr2;
```