# UTF-8 output on Windows console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, utf-8, windows-xp, console

The following code shows unexpected behaviour on my machine (tested with Visual C++ 2008 SP1 on Windows XP and VS 2012 on Windows 7):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 );
    std::cout << "\xc3\xbc";
    int fail = std::cout.fail() ? '1': '0';
    fputc( fail, stdout );
    fputs( "\xc3\xbc", stdout );
}
```

I simply compiled with `cl /EHsc test.cpp`.

**Windows XP:** Output in a console window is`Ã¼0Ã¼` (translated to Codepage 1252, originally shows some line drawing characters in the default Codepage, perhaps 437).

When I change the settings of the console window to use the "Lucida Console" character, set and run my test.exe again, the output is changed to `1ü`, which means:

- the character `ü` can be written using `fputs` and its UTF-8 encoding `C3 BC`;
- `std::cout` does not work for whatever reason;
- the streams `failbit` is setting after trying to write the character.

**Windows 7:** Output using Consolas is `��0ü`. Even more interesting. The correct bytes are written, probably (at least when redirecting the output to a file) and the stream state is ok, but the two bytes are written as separate characters.

I tried to raise this issue on "Microsoft Connect" (see [here), but MS has not been very helpful. You might as well look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371012/how-do-i-print-utf-8-from-c-console-application-on-windows) as something similar has been asked before.

Can you reproduce this problem?

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the `std::cout` and the `fputs` have the same
effect?

Comment: i've had trouble with c++ iostreams before. there's lots of hidden nastiness that causes problems. this isn't worth of an answer, but when iostreams gives you trouble, use c's stdio, i've had to many times before with issues just like this.

Comment: Yes, using iostreams is more complicated than stdio, there are even [full-length text books](http://www.amazon.com/Standard-Iostreams-Locales-Programmers-Reference/dp/0201183951) about this. But iostreams give you a great deal of flexibility, which I am using gladly.

Comment: Is'nt it a problem of the Windows Console ? I remember that it's not unicode aware by any means, creating lot of such problems...

Comment: As you see, I *can* output UTF-8 encoded string in the Windows console (via `fputs`) and I can type UTF-8 encoded files with the `type` command (after having done `chcp 65001`). Thus I thought it can handle this encoding…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to close this now. Stephan T. Lavavej [says](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/detail/431244/std-ostream-fails-to-write-utf-8-encoded-string-to-console) the behaviour is "by design", although I cannot follow this explanation.

My current knowledge is: Windows XP console in UTF-8 codepage does not work with C++ iostreams.

Windows XP is getting out of fashion now and so does VS 2008. I'd be interested to hear if the problem still exists on newer Windows systems.

**On Windows 7** the effect is probably due to the way the C++ streams output characters. As seen in an answer to [Properly print utf8 characters in windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884364/199201), UTF-8 output fails with C stdio when printing one byte after after another like `putc('\xc3'); putc('\xbc');` as well. Perhaps this is what C++ streams do here.

Comment: It exists :( i'm trying to found a workaround in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584160/correct-and-crossplatform-way-to-use-utf-8-in-c-streams You will be welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

I understand the question is quite old, but if someone would still be interested, below is my solution. I've implemented a quite simple std::streambuf descendant and then passed it to each of standard streams on the very beginning of program execution.

This allows you to use UTF-8 everywhere in your program. On input, data is taken from console in Unicode and then converted and returned to you in UTF-8. On output the opposite is done, taking data from you in UTF-8, converting it to Unicode and sending to console. No issues found so far.

Also note, that this solution doesn't require any codepage modification, with either `SetConsoleCP`, `SetConsoleOutputCP` or `chcp`, or something else.

That's the stream buffer:

```
class ConsoleStreamBufWin32 : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    ConsoleStreamBufWin32(DWORD handleId, bool isInput);

protected:
    // std::basic_streambuf
    virtual std::streambuf* setbuf(char_type* s, std::streamsize n);
    virtual int sync();
    virtual int_type underflow();
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c = traits_type::eof());

private:
    HANDLE const m_handle;
    bool const m_isInput;
    std::string m_buffer;
};

ConsoleStreamBufWin32::ConsoleStreamBufWin32(DWORD handleId, bool isInput) :
    m_handle(::GetStdHandle(handleId)),
    m_isInput(isInput),
    m_buffer()
{
    if (m_isInput)
    {
        setg(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

std::streambuf* ConsoleStreamBufWin32::setbuf(char_type* /*s*/, std::streamsize /*n*/)
{
    return 0;
}

int ConsoleStreamBufWin32::sync()
{
    if (m_isInput)
    {
        ::FlushConsoleInputBuffer(m_handle);
        setg(0, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_buffer.empty())
        {
            return 0;
        }

        std::wstring const wideBuffer = utf8_to_wstring(m_buffer);
        DWORD writtenSize;
        ::WriteConsoleW(m_handle, wideBuffer.c_str(), wideBuffer.size(), &writtenSize, NULL);
    }

    m_buffer.clear();

    return 0;
}

ConsoleStreamBufWin32::int_type ConsoleStreamBufWin32::underflow()
{
    if (!m_isInput)
    {
        return traits_type::eof();
    }

    if (gptr() >= egptr())
    {
        wchar_t wideBuffer[128];
        DWORD readSize;
        if (!::ReadConsoleW(m_handle, wideBuffer, ARRAYSIZE(wideBuffer) - 1, &readSize, NULL))
        {
            return traits_type::eof();
        }

        wideBuffer[readSize] = L'\0';
        m_buffer = wstring_to_utf8(wideBuffer);

        setg(&m_buffer[0], &m_buffer[0], &m_buffer[0] + m_buffer.size());

        if (gptr() >= egptr())
        {
            return traits_type::eof();
        }
    }

    return sgetc();
}

ConsoleStreamBufWin32::int_type ConsoleStreamBufWin32::overflow(int_type c)
{
    if (m_isInput)
    {
        return traits_type::eof();
    }

    m_buffer += traits_type::to_char_type(c);
    return traits_type::not_eof(c);
}
```

The usage then is as follows:

```
template<typename StreamT>
inline void FixStdStream(DWORD handleId, bool isInput, StreamT& stream)
{
    if (::GetFileType(::GetStdHandle(handleId)) == FILE_TYPE_CHAR)
    {
        stream.rdbuf(new ConsoleStreamBufWin32(handleId, isInput));
    }
}

// ...

int main()
{
    FixStdStream(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, true, std::cin);
    FixStdStream(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, false, std::cout);
    FixStdStream(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, false, std::cerr);

    // ...

    std::cout << "\xc3\xbc" << std::endl;

    // ...
}
```

Left out `wstring_to_utf8` and `utf8_to_wstring` could easily be implemented with `WideCharToMultiByte` and `MultiByteToWideChar` WinAPI functions.

Comment: That was a helpful idea. For output I ended up with a class derived from `std::stringbuf` (so I don't have to do the buffering by myself) and just implemented `sync()` doing the conversion. Instead of hard-wiring the output sink in the code, my `sync()` inserts the converted string into the streams original streambuf.

Comment: Nice solution! In my Windows7 system, I found that using `SetConsoleOutputCP` function call does not work. Mike.dld's answer works! I found one `wstring_to_utf8` and `utf8_to_wstring` implementation here: [Convert wstring to string encoded in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8), hope that can help others.

Comment: Hi, I found that by using this method, `std::cout` works correctly, but I just tried the `printf("\xc3\xbc");` function, it does not work. Can you help to solve the `printf()` issue? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have one method to solve the `printf()` issue, I just added my solution as an answer in this question.

Comment: @mike.dld: This solution is great, but unfortunately the use case `std::string line; std::getline( std::cin, line );` will not work 100%. Although the input is read correctly to `line` the echo'ed output is garbage, if the UTF-16 representation of the input is assembled as an UTF-16 surrogate pair. All fine if only one UTF-16 byte is needed. This can be easily reproduced using either Command Prompt or PowerShell inside the "Windows Terminal" and then paste e.g.    to the program when it waits in `std::getline`. `ReadConsoleW` (w. `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`) fails on UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the C++ default locale is getting involved. By default, it will use the code page provide by `GetThreadLocale()` to determine the text encoding of non-`wstring` stuff.

This generally defaults to CP1252. You could try using `SetThreadLocale()` to get to UTF-8 (if it even does that, can't recall), with the hope that `std::locale` defaults to something that can handle your UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I looked at this again, but SetThreadLocale does not deal with encoding, or I don't understand the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374051(VS.85).aspx. I tried a little bit with std::cout.imbue but to no avail.

This issue remains unsolved...

Answer (score 0):

I just follow [mike.dld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583456/mike-dld)'s answer in this question, and add the `printf` support for the `UTF-8` string.

As [mkluwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199201/mkluwe) mentioned in his answer that by default, `printf` function will output to the console one by one byte, while the console can't handle single byte correctly. My method is quite simple, I use the `snprintf` function to print the whole content to a internal string buffer, and then dump the buffer to `std::cout`.

Here is the full testing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

// convert UTF-8 string to wstring
std::wstring utf8_to_wstring (const std::string& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.from_bytes(str);
}

// convert wstring to UTF-8 string
std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660492/utf-8-output-on-windows-console
// mike.dld's answer
class ConsoleStreamBufWin32 : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    ConsoleStreamBufWin32(DWORD handleId, bool isInput);

protected:
    // std::basic_streambuf
    virtual std::streambuf* setbuf(char_type* s, std::streamsize n);
    virtual int sync();
    virtual int_type underflow();
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c = traits_type::eof());

private:
    HANDLE const m_handle;
    bool const m_isInput;
    std::string m_buffer;
};

ConsoleStreamBufWin32::ConsoleStreamBufWin32(DWORD handleId, bool isInput) :
    m_handle(::GetStdHandle(handleId)),
    m_isInput(isInput),
    m_buffer()
{
    if (m_isInput)
    {
        setg(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

std::streambuf* ConsoleStreamBufWin32::setbuf(char_type* /*s*/, std::streamsize /*n*/)
{
    return 0;
}

int ConsoleStreamBufWin32::sync()
{
    if (m_isInput)
    {
        ::FlushConsoleInputBuffer(m_handle);
        setg(0, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_buffer.empty())
        {
            return 0;
        }

        std::wstring const wideBuffer = utf8_to_wstring(m_buffer);
        DWORD writtenSize;
        ::WriteConsoleW(m_handle, wideBuffer.c_str(), wideBuffer.size(), &writtenSize, NULL);
    }

    m_buffer.clear();

    return 0;
}

ConsoleStreamBufWin32::int_type ConsoleStreamBufWin32::underflow()
{
    if (!m_isInput)
    {
        return traits_type::eof();
    }

    if (gptr() >= egptr())
    {
        wchar_t wideBuffer[128];
        DWORD readSize;
        if (!::ReadConsoleW(m_handle, wideBuffer, ARRAYSIZE(wideBuffer) - 1, &readSize, NULL))
        {
            return traits_type::eof();
        }

        wideBuffer[readSize] = L'\0';
        m_buffer = wstring_to_utf8(wideBuffer);

        setg(&m_buffer[0], &m_buffer[0], &m_buffer[0] + m_buffer.size());

        if (gptr() >= egptr())
        {
            return traits_type::eof();
        }
    }

    return sgetc();
}

ConsoleStreamBufWin32::int_type ConsoleStreamBufWin32::overflow(int_type c)
{
    if (m_isInput)
    {
        return traits_type::eof();
    }

    m_buffer += traits_type::to_char_type(c);
    return traits_type::not_eof(c);
}

template<typename StreamT>
inline void FixStdStream(DWORD handleId, bool isInput, StreamT& stream)
{
    if (::GetFileType(::GetStdHandle(handleId)) == FILE_TYPE_CHAR)
    {
        stream.rdbuf(new ConsoleStreamBufWin32(handleId, isInput));
    }
}

// some code are from this blog
// https://blog.csdn.net/witton/article/details/108087135

#define printf(fmt, ...) __fprint(stdout, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__ )

int __vfprint(FILE *fp, const char *fmt, va_list va)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315936/which-of-sprintf-snprintf-is-more-secure
    size_t nbytes = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, va) + 1; /* +1 for the '\0' */
    char *str = (char*)malloc(nbytes);
    snprintf(str, nbytes, fmt, va);
    std::cout << str;
    free(str);
    return nbytes;
}

int __fprint(FILE *fp, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    int n = __vfprint(fp, fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    FixStdStream(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, true, std::cin);
    FixStdStream(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, false, std::cout);
    FixStdStream(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, false, std::cerr);

    // ...

    std::cout << "\xc3\xbc" << std::endl;

    printf("\xc3\xbc");

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

The source code is saved in `UTF-8` format, and build under Msys2's GCC and run under Windows 7 64bit. Here is the result

```
ü
ü
```

Answer (score 0):

I make this answer because it really was a head-buster and it is much simpler than it seems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

int main() {

#ifdef _WIN32
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
#endif

  std::string content = "Hello Word ";    
  std::cout << content << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Tested in Windows 11:

```
clang main.cpp -o main.exe -std=c++20
```

Tested in Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```
g++ main.cpp -o test.elf --std=c++20
```