# Convert wstring to string encoded in UTF-8

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, wstring

I need to convert between wstring and string. I figured out, that using codecvt facet should do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work for utf-8 locale.

My idea is, that when I read utf-8 encoded file to chars, one utf-8 character is read into two normal characters (which is how utf-8 works). I'd like to create this utf-8 string from wstring representation for library I use in my code.

Does anybody know how to do it?

I already tried this:

```
  locale mylocale("cs_CZ.utf-8");
  mbstate_t mystate;

  wstring mywstring = L"čřžýáí";

  const codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>& myfacet =
    use_facet<codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t> >(mylocale);

  codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>::result myresult;  

  size_t length = mywstring.length();
  char* pstr= new char [length+1];

  const wchar_t* pwc;
  char* pc;

  // translate characters:
  myresult = myfacet.out (mystate,
      mywstring.c_str(), mywstring.c_str()+length+1, pwc,
      pstr, pstr+length+1, pc);

  if ( myresult == codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>::ok )
   cout << "Translation successful: " << pstr << endl;
  else cout << "failed" << endl;
  return 0;
```

which returns 'failed' for cs_CZ.utf-8 locale and works correctly for cs_CZ.iso8859-2 locale.

Comment: take a look at this link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html might be of some help

Comment: "one utf-8 character is read into two normal characters (which is how utf-8 works)" No it's not.  UTF-16 (mostly) works this way, but a UTF-8 codepoint is represented by one to 4 bytes, and a "character" can consist of multiple codepoints.

Comment: ephimient - yes - I know it, I just wrote it badly :)

Answer (score -10, accepted):

C++ has no idea of Unicode. Use an external library such as ICU ([`UnicodeString` class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html)) or Qt ([`QString` class](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html)), both support Unicode, including UTF-8.

Comment: -1 not really true, C++ supports locales which includes encoding (unfortunately this is broken for UTF-8 on Windows)

Comment: Agree. C++ doesn't _guarantee_ Unicode, or the existence of `locale ("cs_CZ.utf-8");`. But if you've got a system with that locale, it better work.

Comment: No longer true as of C++11.  `char16_t` is specifically intended for UTF-16, and `char32_t` is specifically intended for UTF-32; C++14 expands on this, by requiring that the `char` types be large enough to store 256 distinct values specifically to be suitable for UTF-8.  C++11 also added classes `codecvt_utf8`, `codecvt_utf16`, and `codecvt_utf8_utf16`, as well as two new specialisations of `codecvt` (`std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` and `std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t>`).  So, C++ now officially supports UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, UCS2, and UCS4.

Comment: Out of those `codecvt`s: `codecvt_utf8` converts between UTF-8 and UCS2/UCS4, `codecvt_utf16` converts between UTF-16 and UCS2/UCS4, `codecvt_utf8_utf16` converts between UTF-8 and UTF-16, `codecvt`'s `char16_t` specialisation is also for UTF-8 and UTF-16, and `codecvt`'s `char32_t` specialisation converts between UTF-8 and UTF-32.  Not 100% sure of exactly how they work yet, I actually just started learning Unicode conversion today.

Answer (score 96):

The code below might help you :)

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

// convert UTF-8 string to wstring
std::wstring utf8_to_wstring (const std::string& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.from_bytes(str);
}

// convert wstring to UTF-8 string
std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}
```

Comment: But not on linux using libstdc++.

Comment: While the above work. I strongly suggest looking into Unicode library such as ICU and Boost.Locale.

Comment: It works like a charm for any `std::wstring`. Small test here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37531136/1802974

Comment: you might also need  #include <locale>, otherwise it should build fine with libc++

Comment: Dude... Spent hours trying to do this properly on windows to give a COM port to CreateFileW... Thank You!

Comment: `codecvt` is deprecated as of C++17 and there is no replacement.

Comment: @AlexReinking cpp reference doesn't say that codecvt is deprecated. While some members are deprecated, there are new ones that are added (eg. C++20 adds ```std::codecvt<char32_t, char8_t, std::mbstate_t>```).
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt

Comment: Note that this code does not work with emojis on Windows . I posted a platform-independent version [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76943362/758345).

Answer (score 9):

What's your platform? Note that Windows does not support UTF-8 locales so this may explain why you're failing.

To get this done in a platform dependent way you can use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202786.aspx)/[WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows and [iconv](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/iconv.3.html) on Linux. You may be able to use some boost magic to get this done in a platform independent way, but I haven't tried it myself so I can't add about this option.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you have to use std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>! Otherwise your conversion will fail on Unicode code points that need two 16 bit code units. Like  (U+1F609)

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

// convert UTF-8 string to wstring
std::wstring utf8_to_wstring (const std::string& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.from_bytes(str);
}

// convert wstring to UTF-8 string
std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use boost's utf_to_utf converter to get char format to store in std::string.

```
std::string myresult = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(my_wstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [currently most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903901/758345) is not platform-independent. It breaks on non-BMP characters (i.e. Emojis ). JWiesemann already pointed this out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73412919/758345), but their code will only work on windows.

So here's a correct platform-independent version:

```cpp
#include <codecvt>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

std::string wstring_to_utf8(std::wstring const& str)
{
  std::wstring_convert<std::conditional_t<
        sizeof(wchar_t) == 4,
        std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,
        std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>> converter;
  return converter.to_bytes(str);
}

std::wstring utf8_to_wstring(std::string const& str)
{
  std::wstring_convert<std::conditional_t<
        sizeof(wchar_t) == 4,
        std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,
        std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>> converter;
  return converter.from_bytes(str);
}
```

On msvc this might generate some deprecation warnings. You can disable these by wrapping the functions in

```cpp
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
<the two functions>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/758345) to another question as to why it's ok to disable that warning.

Answer (score -1):

What locale does is that it gives the program information about the external encoding, but assuming that the internal encoding didn't change. If you want to output UTF-8 you need to do it from `wchar_t` not from `char*`.

What you could do is output it as raw data (not string), it should be then correctly interpreted if the systems locale is UTF-8.

Plus when using `(w)cout`/`(w)cerr`/`(w)cin` you need to imbue the locale on the stream.

Comment: UTF-_8_ uses _8_-bit code units.  `char` (as well as `signed char` and `unsigned char`) must be a minimum of _8_ bits.  I believe you may be thinking of UTF-16, UTF-32, UCS2, or UCS4.

Answer (score -2):

The [Lexertl library](http://www.benhanson.net/lexertl.html) has an iterator that lets you do this:

```
std::string str;
str.assign(
  lexertl::basic_utf8_out_iterator<std::wstring::const_iterator>(wstr.begin()),
  lexertl::basic_utf8_out_iterator<std::wstring::const_iterator>(wstr.end()));
```