# How to send query to populate utf8 VARCHAR column using Connector/C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, utf-8, mysql-connector

In my C++ application (On Windows x64 being developed using VS2012) I am using MySQL Connector/C++ to connect MySQL database. I've table ALL_USERNAMES that has a column:

```
USERNAME VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

However, I am not sure how can I fire utf8 queries through my C++ application. Method `sql::Statement::executeUpdate` accepts `sql::SQLString` type. It is essentially `std::string`.

So if I do something like this:

```
std::string strQuery = "INSERT INTO ALL_USERNAMES (USERNAME) VALUES ('अतुल')"
executeUpdate(strQuery);
```

And when I check the table record through MySQL  Workbench I see USERNAME as all question marks (???????).

I couldn't find anything about this in Connector/C++ documentation. Any idea how to solve this?

**What I wanted to try:**

In MySQL C API there are functions like:

```
mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8"); 
mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

which I wanted to try as I suspect it will solve my problem. 
But I couldn't find its counterpart in Connector/C++.

**UPDATE:**

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` gives me this:

```
'ALL_USERNAMES', 'CREATE TABLE `all_usernames` (\n  `USERNAME` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

And my client code is here (this was before I written my own answer):

```
sql::Connection *m_pConnection = NULL;
sql::Statement *m_pStatement = NULL;
sql::Driver *driver = NULL;

driver = get_driver_instance();
m_pConnection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "username", "password");
m_pConnection->setSchema("DBNAME");
m_pStatement = m_pConnection->createStatement();
int RetVal = m_pStatement->executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ALL_USERNAMES (USERNAME) VALUES ('अतुल')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do this with the help of an answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8).

1. First get the unicode string in `wstring` for example:

   ```
   std::wstring wname = _T("अतुल");
   ```
2. Then convert the string above to utf-8 string using this function:

   ```
   #include <codecvt>
   #include <string>

   // convert wstring to UTF-8 string
   std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str)
   {
       std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
       return myconv.to_bytes(str);
   }
   ```

   Thus our string becomes:

   ```
   std::string name = wstring_to_utf8(wname);
   ```
3. You can now use the obtained `std::string` in MySQL query:

   ```
   std::string strQuery = "INSERT INTO ALL_USERNAMES (USERNAME) VALUES ('" + name + "')";
   ```

Comment: If you `SELECT HEX(col) ...`, do you get `E0A485E0A4A4E0A581E0A4B2` for `अतुल`?  (That is the utf8  encoding for it.)

Comment: Yes, I get exactly same.

Answer (score 2):

- Do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface; use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
- Use `mysqli_set_charset('utf8');`, not the commands indicated.
- Question marks occur because:

  - The client has a valid character (good), and
  - The `SET NAMES` agrees with the encoding that the client has (good), but
  - The target column's `CHARACTER SET` does not include the intended character. So...
- Declare the `USERNAME` to be `CHARACTER SET ut8`.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you have already done such.)

Comment: As per current implementation I don't call any `mysql_*` or `my_sqli_*` functions. I've updated question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output and C++ source (in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows x64). Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: The source code above was giving me warnings `warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u0905' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)` which I thought because `std::string` can't accept unicode literals. So I have to use `std::wstring` and `_T()` for unicode for that. Then all it needed is to convert that unicode to `std::string`. And for that I used method I mentioned in my answer. Please let me know is this approach correct?

Comment: FYI, \u0905 represents DEVANAGARI LETTER A = अ

Comment: Yes it's 'A' of Devnagari :)