# Which of sprintf/snprintf is more secure?

Tags: c, security, unix, printf, secure-coding

I wish to know which of these two options is the more secure one to use:

```
#define MAXLEN 255
char buff[MAXLEN + 1]
```

1. `sprintf(buff, "%.*s", MAXLEN, name)`
2. `snprintf(buff, MAXLEN, "%s", name)`

My understanding is that both are same. Please suggest.

Comment: Change #2 to `MAXLEN+1` and they'll be identical in what they write into `buff` in all cases (the return value will be different if `strlen(name) > 255`).

Answer (score 51):

The two expressions you gave are *not* equivalent: `sprintf` takes no argument specifying the maximum number of bytes to write; it simply takes a destination buffer, a format string, and a bunch of arguments. Therefore, it may write more bytes than your buffer has space for, and in so doing write arbitrary code. The `%.*s` is not a satisfactory solution because:

1. When the format specifier refers to length, it's referring to the equivalent of `strlen`; this is a measure of the number of characters in the string, not its length in memory (i.e. it doesn't count the null terminator).
2. Any change in the format string (adding a newline, for example) will change the behavior of the `sprintf` version with respect to buffer overflows. With `snprintf`, a fixed, clear maximum is set regardless of changes in the format string or input types.

Comment: Actually, about 1, I was mistaken - it does specify the maximum number of characters (but without counting the `\0`). I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - I remembered there being some problem with that format specifier, and assumed you were right :-P

Comment: Well, this all depends on what kind of security the OP's question is about. Formally a properly used `sprintf` is as secure in this specific case as `snprintf`. What you are talking about in this answer is the lack of protection from lazy/incompetent programmer. Whether the OP was asking about this side of security I don't know.

Comment: I'm assuming that the string `name` is provided by an untrusted user; that's the only case where this is a security issue at all, and in that case it is a rather serious one. With a really bad `sprintf` format string, a malicious user carefully crafting their input can overwrite the stack and execute arbitrary code; with this format string, a malicious user can only overwrite one byte on the stack with a zero (the null terminator), which might be a pretty effective DOS attack.

Comment: Still, a *good* format string provides the same level of protection as `snprintf` (again, applied to string input specifically).

Comment: It does, but it's much less verifiable - it's hard to look at an `sprintf` call and, at a glance, establish an upper limit to the memory it will overwrite.

Answer (score 27):

The best and most flexible way would be to use `snprintf`!

```
size_t nbytes = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s", name) + 1; /* +1 for the '\0' */
char *str = malloc(nbytes);
snprintf(str, nbytes, "%s", name);
```

In C99, `snprintf` returns the number of bytes written to the string excluding the `'\0'`. If there were less than the necessary amount of bytes, `snprintf` returns the number of bytes that would have been necessary to expand the format (still excluding the `'\0'`). By passing `snprintf` a string of 0 length, you can find out ahead of time how long the expanded string would have been, and use it to allocate the necessary memory.

Comment: Yes, this is the best approach, I don't know why this answer is not voted to the top. Users usually don't know that they can put NULL as the first argument.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html takes it one step further and just allicates it for you.  GNU extension.

Comment: Performance-wise, does this solution use about double the time?

Answer (score 15):

For the simple example in the question, there might not be much difference in the security between the two calls. However, in the general case `snprintf()` is probably more secure. Once you have a more complex format string with multiple conversion specifications it can be difficult (or near impossible) to ensure that you have the buffer length accounted for accurately across the different conversions - especially since a previous conversions don't necessarily produce a fixed number of output characters.

So, I'd stick with `snprintf()`.

Another small advantage to `snprintf()` (though not security related) is that it'll tell you how big of a buffer you need.

A final note - you should specify the actual buffer size in the `snprintf()` call - it'll handle accounting for the null terminator for you:

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s", name);
```

Comment: I think it's worth stating explicitly that for your last line of code, `buff` has to be an array on the stack. If you have a `char *`, it won't work. (Well, it _might_, but it won't work all the time, at least.) Yes, it works _in OP's case_, but the reason why is subtle to new people using this as a reference.

Comment: Nic, can you support that 'has to be an array on the stack' claim with a cite?

Answer (score 12):

I would say `snprintf()` is much more better until I read this passage:

[https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding/838-BSI.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130221150315/https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding/838-BSI.html)

Short summary is: `snprintf()` not portable its behaviour change from system to system. The most serious problem with `snprintf()` can occur when `snprintf()` is implemented simply by calling `sprintf()`.You may think it protects you from buffer overflow and let your guard down, but it may not.

So now I am still saying `snprintf()` safer but also being cautious when I use it.

Comment: `snprintf` is specified in ISO C 99, which was 14 years before this answer, and 24 before today.   The 2007-dated reference cited is correctly stating that `snprintf` is not in C90 and there have been different variants of it. But ... so what?

Answer (score 6):

There's an important difference between these two -- the `snprintf` call will scan the `name` argument to the end (terminating NUL) in order to figure out the correct return value.  The `sprintf` call on the other hand will read AT MOST 255 characters from `name`.

So if `name` is a pointer to a non-NUL terminated buffer with at least 255 characters, the `snprintf` call might run off the end of the buffer and trigger undefined behavior (such as crashing), while the `sprintf` version will not.

Answer (score 3):

Your sprintf statement is correct, but I'd not be self-confident enough to use that for safety purpose (e.g. missing one cryptic char and you're shieldless) while there is snprintf around that can be applied to any format ... oh wait *snprintf is not in ANSI C*. It is (only?) C99. That could be a (weak) reason to prefer the other one.

Well. You could use `strncpy`, too, couldn't you ?

e.g.

```
  char buffer[MAX_LENGTH+1];
  buffer[MAX_LENGTH]=0;             // just be safe in case name is too long
  strncpy(buffer,MAX_LENGTH,name);  // strncpy will never overwrite last byte
```

Comment: And are you sure that the `%.*s` is available in ANSI C? I've tried to find the specification, but could only find one (untrustworthy) reference that did not specify the `.*`.

Comment: @Eli: Specifying the precision (as here) or the field width as an asterisk has been in ANSI C since the original standard (1989/1990).  `snprintf()` was added in the C99 standard.

Comment: @Michael - for string (`%s`) also? That's good to know, thanks.

Comment: No, `strncpy`is not what he wants, search for `strlcpy` here on SO to see why. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure/2115015#2115015

Comment: @quinmars: that's a long babble from AndreyT you point me at here... If i try to summarize, the bad thing with strncpy is that it might not put a trailing '\0' if source string is too long, right ? that sounds easy enough to overcome to me (see updated code in my post). Now that might be felt "unsafe" because missing the additional "buffer[N]=0" will leave you unshielded. Or is there anything else I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

So this was the first stack overflow related question that came up when searching for sprintf vs snprintf. So I figured this was the best place to add this answer.

It seems it's not an option to use sprintf on OSX 13.3 now because I'm getting these warnings.

> 'sprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility
> reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of
> sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead.
> [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]

So I went through and converted them all to

```
snprintf(char * restrict str, size_t size, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

It was pretty straight forward and it's always safer to use snprintf vs sprintf.

Answer (score -1):

Both will give the result you want, but `snprintf` is more generic, and will protect your string from overruns no matter the format string given.

In addition, because `snprintf` (or `sprintf` for that matter) adds a final `\0`, you should make the string buffer one byte bigger, `char buff[MAXLEN + 1]`.

Comment: That turns out not to be the case. From the snprintf doc: "The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() write at most size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to str."