# traversal of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I'm trying to create a program to work with binary search trees and my instructor has this function set up with this declaration, which must stay the same.

```
void BSTType<T>::traverse(std::ostream& out, TravType trav) const{
```

this is currently how i have it implemented, but what is the std::ostream& out used for and how do i use this is my main program? I don't understand why we need this as a parameter and not the current tree I am working with. please help soon. this is due at 8pm and my instructor won't help. if more info is needed just let me know in comments or something.

```
template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::traverse(std::ostream& out, TravType trav) const{
    if(trav==IN)
        inorder(root);
    else if(trav=PRE)
        preorder(root);
    else
        postorder(root);
}
```

this is the idea i have for calling this function from my main program

```
tree.traverse(???, IN);
```

this should output the tree using inorder traversal by calling the inorder(root) function. I don't understand what goes where the question marks are

here are my functions that traverse can call, depending on what travType the user enters

```
void BSTType<T>::inorder(BTNodeType<T>* node) const{
    if (node!= NULL){
        inorder(node->left);
        std::cout << node->item << " ";
        inorder(node->right);
    }
}

template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::postorder(BTNodeType<T>* node) const{
    if (node!= NULL){
        postorder(node->left);
        postorder(node->right);
        std::cout << node->item << " ";
    }
}

template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::preorder(BTNodeType<T>* node) const{
    if(node!=NULL){
        std::cout << node->item<< " ";
        preorder(node-> left);
        preorder(node-> right);
    }
}
```

**edit:**
for some reason this function isn't copying my tree correctly, anyone know why?

```
template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::copy(BTNodeType<T>*& node1, BTNodeType<T>* node2){
    if(node2==NULL)
        node1=NULL;
    else{
        node1=new BTNodeType<T>;
        node1->item=node2->item;
        copy(node1->left, node2->left);
        copy(node1->right, node2->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: More information is needed. What **exactly** is this function supposed to do? And we do not know that `root, preorder, postorder, trav or IN` are

Comment: this function is suppose to call the 'inorder' 'postorder' or 'preorder' function based on what the user inputs for their traversal type which is either 'IN' 'POST' or 'PRE'

Comment: oh, and root is the root node in my binary search tree(where the traversal will begin)

Comment: 5:08 pm here in central US.

Comment: should it be (*node1)=new BTNodeType<T>; ?

Answer (score 2):

***`tree.traverse(???, IN);` I don't understand what goes where the question marks are.***

You could just put:

??? = `std::cout`

If you want to print at the standard output (i.e., it needs an [output stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/?kw=ostream)).

Also it's recommended to pass the output stream as input argument to the member functions you posted, that is your member functions will become:

```
 void BSTType<T>::inorder(BTNodeType<T>* node, std::ostream& out) const{
    if (node!= 0){
        inorder(node->left);
        out << node->item << " ";
        inorder(node->right);
    }
}

template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::postorder(BTNodeType<T>* node, std::ostream& out) const{
    if (node!= 0){
        postorder(node->left);
        postorder(node->right);
        out << node->item << " ";
    }
}

template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::preorder(BTNodeType<T>* node, std::ostream& out) const{
    if(node!=0){
        out << node->item<< " ";
        preorder(node-> left);
        preorder(node-> right);
    }
}
```

---

Then `traverse` will become:

```
template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::traverse(std::ostream& out, TravType trav) const{
    if(trav==IN)
        inorder(root, out);
    else if(trav=PRE)
        preorder(root, out);
    else
        postorder(root, out);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i have!

Comment: can you look at my copy function please?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ostream& out
```

is the output stream, used to append the different node information when visited, in order to be able to print the whole tree in the order it was visited.

The algorithm should be something like this: `out << node.getValue()`. This would append the current value to the output string. According to each algorithm, the order of the calls will change, but they will all result in a different order of this 3 actions: append the node's information, then call left or right child.

`inorder(root);` should be replaced by `inorder(out, root);`

Inside inorder it should have: `out << root.getValue()` to append the value

Add: `using namespace std;` so you can call `tree.traverse(cout, IN);` to use the standard output

Comment: I've never used c++, but this may help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106102/how-to-use-c-stdostream-with-printf-like-formatting

Comment: I know that that is the output stream, but how do i use it in this situation?

Comment: It should be something like this: out << node.getValue(). This would append the current value to the output string. According to each algorithm, the order of the calls will change, but they will all result in a different order of this 3 actions: append the node's information, then call left or right child.

Comment: it wont let me comment on this the way i want to so check my edits in my post. i added my functions 'inorder' 'preorder' and 'postorder'

Comment: inorder(root); should be replaced by inorder(out, root); and inside inorder it should have: out << root.getValue() to append the value

Comment: and if you add: using namespace std; you can call tree.traverse(cout, IN); where cout is the standard output

Comment: ok, but after i change that, how do i call this in my main program

Comment: ok, sorry! thanks for all your help, I'm retarded. I figured it out, in the main program you just say tree.traverse(cout, IN); like 40two said!

Comment: can you look at my copy function please?