# std::string aware options for vsprintf

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have an old MUD codebase in C (>80k lines) that uses printf-style string formatting.  It is pervasive -- almost every bit of text runs through calls to either sprintf or a wrapper around vsprintf.  However, I have recently moved to compiling with g++ to take advantage of the STL, and would like to use std::string (actually a derived class for default case-insensitive comparisons) where it makes sense.

Obviously, you can't pass std::string as one of the variadic arguments to any of the printf functions: I need .c_str() in every case.  I don't want to do that, mostly because ***I don't want to modify 2000+ calls to printf functions***.  My question is: ***how can I make a std::string aware vsprintf***?

The way I see it, I have two options: write my own printf functions that iterate through the arguments changing pointers to std::string to std::string.data (or c_out()) before passing to std::vsprintf, or I can borrow the guts of printf and roll my own.  The first option sounds like less work, obviously.

Of course, a better option is if someone has done this before, but my googling is yielding nothing.  Any tips on what the best option would look like?

EDIT:
This question was closed as a duplicate of [How to use C++ std::ostream with printf-like formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106102/how-to-use-c-stdostream-with-printf-like-formatting), which I don't believe answers the question.  I'm not asking how to output strings with std::ostream vs the old C printf.  I'm asking for help with a patch solution for an old C codebase that makes extensive use of sprintf/vsprintf, without rewriting thousands of calls to those functions to use output streams.

Comment: _">80k lines"_ That's just peanuts.

Comment: Reopened. Read the question: this is **not** about `ostream`, but about `string`. Yes, they both come from `namespace std`, but there is little more they have in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own `printf` wrapper, that extracts `char const*` from `std::string`. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

template<class T>
inline auto to_c(T&& arg) -> decltype(std::forward<T>(arg)) {
    return std::forward<T>(arg);
}

inline char const* to_c(std::string const& s) { return s.c_str(); }
inline char const* to_c(std::string& s) { return s.c_str(); }

template<class... Args>
int my_printf(char const* fmt, Args&&... args) {
    return std::printf(fmt, to_c(args)...);
}

int main() {
    std::string name = "World";
    my_printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

---

Or, better, switch to a modern C++ formatting library, such as [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

Comment: YUCK! When switching to C++, take advantage of the other types C++ can format!

Comment: I would +1 the fmt, if it was the only thing in the answer. There is no excuse for cooking anything up with all the existing options around.

Comment: The fmt library looks very interesting, and I may end up using that at a later date.  To solve my particular problem, the example code is working very well.  I think it makes a simple building block to modernizing my code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The common advice is [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/format/example/sample_formats.cpp)

Taking their example:

```
// printf directives's type-flag can be used to pass formatting options :
std::cout <<  format("_%1$4d_ is : _%1$#4x_, _%1$#4o_, and _%1$s_ by default\n")  % 18;
//          prints  "_  18_ is : _0x12_, _ 022_, and _18_ by default\n"
```

Now this assumes `std::ostream&`, so you'll need a `std::stringstream` to use a `std::string` as the backing buffer.

PS. using a derived class for case-insensitive comparisons sounds like a bad idea waiting to bite you. You just need a custom order; all the STL functions that assume ordering have overloads to support custom orderings.