# Which is the best way to print to the console in c++?

Tags: c++

I have read three ways to print things to the console in c++ from various sources.

1. Using `using namespace std;` and then using `cout` (*CodeBlocks Standard*)
2. Not using the above and using `std::cout` and `std::endl;` (*C++ Primer*)
3. Using `printf` (*HackerRank*)

**Which is preferred and why?**

Comment: Both 1 and 2 are really the same. And using `printf` isn't type-safe.

Comment: I don't suggest using `using namespace std;` unless it's for a small project. You're likely to cause ambiguities. Since it's c++ `std::cout` is what people usually go for.

Comment: Please, pretty please, do not try to learn C++ from hackerrank. That would ende ***very*** poorly.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: 1 and 2 are a matter of style, and context dependent as to when one would be used over the other.  3 is not strictly C++, but _also_ has it's place.  There are major drawbacks to variable argument functions (like `printf`) though.

Comment: In c++ use option 2.

Comment: For option 1 read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice#1452738

Comment: It is bad practise to use `using namespace std` at global scope because of namespace pollution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))

Comment: one advantage of `printf` that isn't talked about is the internal locking witch make it better then `std::cout`  for multi-thread programs

Comment: @JeJo What is a good alternative for practice along with learning theory ?

Comment: To those closing this question as primarily opinion based, this question has a distinct answer. It is not opinion based at all.

Comment: Short answer: none of the above.  C++ doesn't have a concept of "console".  I'd suggest that `std::clog` (or `std::wclog`) is likely to be the closest approximation.

Answer (score 22):

Number 2 with amendment. (`std::cout` and `'\n'`)

Why?

1. Because you should avoid `using namespace std`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
2. (*Among other reasons*) Because `cout` is typesafe and `printf` is not.  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
3. `std::endl` will force a flush of the output buffer to the console. Unless you specifically want this to happen use `<< '\n'` or `<< "...string\n"`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 6):

Unless you really care about speed, both cout and printf are fine. If you want faster runtimes, here are a few pointers :

- Use only printf with no cout. This will give more speed than using a mixture of printf and cout or just cout.
- Or use only cout but add the following at the beginning of execution
  `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);` . There are two separate streams for printf and cout and they are synchronized by default. Lot of running time is wasted due to this synchronisation. These two lines of code will stop the synchronisation, but take care that you don't use any printf if you add these lines, otherwise printing might happen in random order.
- Do not use `endl` unless you want to flush the output buffer. Lots of endl can make the code slower. Use `cout<<'\n';` instead.

Comment: If you want speed, don't print. Write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Both your first points do basically the same thing. It's better practice to use `std::` instead of `using namespace std;` as the latter pollutes the global namespace and can cause naming conflicts.

Something not mentioned is that you can selectively expose parts of a namespace with `using <namespace>::<element>;` (e.g. `using std::cout;`). It's still better practice to be verbose with your statements, but this option still isn't as bad as exposing the entire namespace.

`printf` isn't as safe as `cout` (the stream `<<` operators do a good job of printing what you want), you ought to avoid it while starting out.

Comment: Especially as beginner I would recommend not to use `using namespace std;` and specify `std::` each time, just to get used to reading code like that. But just as you stated, it can get highly opinionated.

Comment: @AlexMeuer Putting `using namespace …` in a *header*, at namespace scope, is almost universally considered bad practice, though, just to be a bit more specific here.

Answer (score 1):

these is my debugger code that during these 10 years of c++ working helped me.

```
std::ostream &debugRecord (const char* fileName, int lineNum, const char* funcName)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(streamMutex_);
    return std::cout << "Thread # " << getCurrentThreadId() << " -- "
                     << "(" << fileName << ":" << lineNum << "): " << funcName << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: printf did not do it very well for me and confused me so i do it with cout and get good results. also << operation help very much

Comment: You should mention which headers you need for the concurrency API you use (where does `getCurrentThreadId()` come from?)

Comment: getCurrentThreadId() is function which i write it before. but if you need it tell me to write it here for you.

Comment: No, not necessary; but you should mention that in the answer and make it obvious that your code is just a proposal or template, nothing which can directly be copied and pasted. I liked it though, even if the OP's question was probably more general.

Comment: Why are you using `std::cout` for debugging, instead of `std::clog` (which is provided for *exactly* that purpose)?  You really don't want your logging mixed up with your program output!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends a lot on what you want to do. For output which largely uses default formats `cout` is indeed preferred because of the type safety and because it's very intuitive.

If you want to heavily format your output though I can only recommend the surprisingly versatile and straight-forward `printf` because manipulators in cout are a pain. True: The `printf` format syntax, does, let's say, take some getting used to, but it's surely worth it. Just double check the format string, listen to the warnings of your compiler, and use the proper format specifiers e.g. for `size_t` and other system dependent data in order to stay portable.

There is also a boost facility for combining streams and `printf` style formatting, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106194/3150802, but I have never used it. Perhaps somebody can comment on its usability?