No Output When Reading and Printing UTF-16LE File with Windows API
I have encountered an issue with Windows API I/O output that has been troubling me for several days. I want to perform a file read operation using the CreateFile function in the Windows API, reading from a target text file (txt). I want the system to read the file content into a buffer that I defined, and then I attempt to print the contents of this buffer to the console.
However, after attempting to print from the buffer, the console shows no output at all. I have tried various approaches but ultimately failed to resolve the issue. The text file is encoded in UTF-16LE and contains 500 Chinese characters that need to be printed to the console.
Here is my source code (with the output shown below it):
   #include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> // For std::size_t
#include <cstdint> // For std::uint8_t

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Create file handle
    HANDLE win_file = CreateFile2(
        L"C:\\win32tese.txt",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        NULL
    );
    if (win_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << "Failed to open file, error code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Start reading data from file
    wchar_t win_buffer[101] = {}; // Buffer
    DWORD win_Transmission = 0;
    BOOL win_Read = ReadFile(
        win_file,
        &win_buffer,
        100,
        &win_Transmission,
        NULL
    );
    wcout << "Bytes transferred: " << win_Transmission << endl;

    if (win_Read == 0) {
        cout << "Read operation failed, error code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        wcout << win_buffer[i];
    }

    CloseHandle(win_file);
    return 0;
}
Output in Console:
Bytes transferred: 100

C:\VS_2022\Win32Development\x64\Debug\Win32Development.exe (process 23212) exited with code 0 (0x0).

To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Debugging" -> "Automatically close the console when debugging stops."
Press any key to close this window . . .
Hopefully, this translation will help clarify my issue on Stack Overflow. Thank you for your assistance!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50617681/4165552  -- possible dupe?

You appear to be reading the file correctly.  But printing unicode chars to the console in Windows requires some additional steps. It's been answered many times before on SO.

std::wstring s(win_buffer,win_Read); MessageBoxW(NULL, s.c_str(), L"message", MB_OK); should show a message box with your string in it. Put that code in in place of the wcout statements.

ReadFile() reads bytes so you're passing a too-short length. Should be something like sizeof(wchar_t) * 100, not 100. And then that for loop should only attempt to write the characters actually read, not the entire array.
