# How to implement console and file input/output functionality to work with UTF-8 encoding in MinGW?

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, mingw

I want to use Cyrillic letters in my application, and I decided to use UTF-8 encoding to store any text data. I'm using MinGW on Windows 7, source files are encoded in UTF-8. I read a lot of info about encoding and different ways to convert strings, change locales, set stream modes and etc., but I didn't find a proper way to implement all next needs at once:

1. Read keyboard input from stdio using console [`GetConsoleCP` shows that it's `cp866; OEM Russian; Cyrillic (DOS)` for me]. Then it should be somehow converted to proper encoding to write these strings, so next:
2. Be able to write to stdout the data came from stdin (with correct representation of characters) using console [`GetConsoleOutputCP` shows that it's `cp866; OEM Russian; Cyrillic (DOS)` for me].
3. Be able to write to stdout the data came from source files (i.e. `const char` arrays) [source files are encoded in `UTF-8`].
4. Read and write data to UTF-8 encoded text files.

What I've tried:

1. Combinations of `SetConsoleCP` and `SetConsoleOutputCP` functions.
2. Combinations of `_setmode ()` function and `_O_U8TEXT` macros.
3. `setlocale` stuff.
4. Combinations of point 1-3 and `wchar_t` strings, using `wscanf`/`wcin` and L-strings.

So, is there a way to implement listed above functionality?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Properly print utf8 characters in windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882277/properly-print-utf8-characters-in-windows-console)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/amanuellperez/alp/blob/master/src/alp_utf8.h) can help you. And if you want an example of how to use that library, [look here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/alp/blob/master/src/test/utf8/main.cpp)