# Passing strings with non-ASCII characters from NodeJS to C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I am trying to send a string containing non-ASCII characters from node to a C++ native module but I seem to be getting garbage instead of the special characters (regular ASCII ones are ok).

In JS I just call my function with this hardcoded string **"/ÿaddoné/"** but on the C++ side I get **"/ï¿½addonï¿½/"**.

I use the following to print the string

```
std::cout << std::string(*v8::String::Utf8Value(obj->Get(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "data")))) << std::endl;
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your console can display the characters?

Comment: Seems like related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575863/how-to-print-utf-8-strings-to-stdcout-on-windows

Comment: the console can display the characters, if I do cout << "/ÿaddoné/" it prints fine

Comment: @user1233963 (with regards to that cout test): are you sure your source file is encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: @Frank no, the cpp source file was ISO 8859-1, I converted to UTF-8 and it now it doesn't work. What's the idea here?

Comment: @user1233963 See ÖöTiib's comment, it's exactly that. In short, `cout` doesn't interpret utf-8, it just passes the bytes to the console as-is, which interprets them based on its configuration (in Windows: ISO 8859-1)

Comment: @Frank I don't understand. What's the encoding of the cpp file have to do with this ? I send the string from js (source is also 8859-1) how is that related ?

Comment: @user1233963 the fact that it printed correctly when the file was encoded as ISO 8859-1 proves that your console is interpreting the string as that encoding. Your code forces a conversion to UTF-8, which is going to be a mismatch.

Comment: @Frank how should I get the value without forcing the conversion?