# Visual studio character encoding issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encoding

I've just downloaded Visual studio 2019, but I have a problem with string encoding.
This is my code in C++:

```
cout << "èà" << "\n" << endl;

string str;
cout << "Write something: "
cin >> str;
cout << str << endl
```

The output of the first line is:

```
├¿├á
```

If I give "èà" as input at line 5 though, the output is:

```
èà
```

I can't understand why. Can you help me please?

The source file encoding is UTF-8, I've already checked.

Please, be specific in your answers, because I've just started with Visual Studio.

Comment: `cin` and `cout` don't use UTF-8 in Windows.

Comment: The problem is not VS but encoding of console/terminal which is (based on your description)  not utf-8.

Comment: I can't test it myself right now but this might help [How do I print UTF-8 from c++ console application on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371012/how-do-i-print-utf-8-from-c-console-application-on-windows), and here the official docs [execution_character_set pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/execution-character-set?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Maybe also [How to print UTF-8 strings to std::cout on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575863/how-to-print-utf-8-strings-to-stdcout-on-windows)

Comment: It's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)  (Python example: `"èà".encode('utf-8').decode('cp437')` returns `'├¿├á'`).

Comment: @Thena3033 I suggest you could try to set the output code page programmatically: `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`

Answer (score -1):

STD C++ 20 Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <clocale>
#endif

int main() {
#ifdef _WIN32
  // console UTF-8
  std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".UTF8");
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
#endif

  std::string str = "呐㗂越  αβγδ ñ";
  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

MSVC requires the following flags:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
target_compile_options(hello_world PRIVATE /source-charset:utf-8 /execution-charset:utf-8)
```

If you don't add those flags it will never be able to print the characters correctly, this problem doesn't seem to happen with clang.

The problem is that the characters are printed in the console incorrectly if the described flags are not set, but in reality the operation from STD 20 onwards will be as UTF-8, similar to modern Linux operating systems.

Comment: *" this problem doesn't seem to happen with clang...."* What is the actual problem? How does this answer solve it? An answer should answer these questions.

Comment: The problem is that the characters are printed in the console incorrectly if the described flags are not set.