# What type should I be using to store and print these unicode characters? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, command-line-interface, utf

I'm writing a CLI version of the game Snake in C++, and I want to make the snake look cool using different unicode characters to represent different states of the snake. I am using the following characters : ╔, ╗, ╚, ╝, ═, ║, ⩓, ⩔, ⪡, ⪢.

I originally started programming this in Xcode on my Mac, and had no problem what so ever storing them as `const char *`s.

[image: Image of game running in Xcode on Macos]

Running the same code in Visual Studio on Windows, renders much less beautiful results.

[image: Image of game running on Windows (Visual Studio)]

Since discovering this, I've been reading all about Unicode and UTF encoding and still do not understand what I should be doing to make these characters to display properly on both Windows and MacOS.

Comment: The problem isn't so much the "characters" you're writing, as the [code page](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/codepage.htm) Windows is using to render those characters.  You can find many links on the subject, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45588456/421195

Comment: This might be more of a windows issue than a C++ issue. You might look for unicode and windows cmd.

Comment: There are a ton of questions on StackOverflow related to how to print Unicode output on a Windows console. I'm sure you can find a duplicate if you search.

Comment: @paulsm4 I tried copying the code from that answer and replacing the symbol with "⪢". This printed a question mark in a box, so it didn't quite work. It did say `'initializing': truncation from 'char16_t' to 'char'` in the build out put though. maybe fixing that could fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

Comment: the easiest way would be [changing Windows to en_US.UTF-8 locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

Comment: @Eljay it has for years. Did you even click that link?

Comment: @Eljay `en_US.UTF-8` is standard in other platforms. The last part is the name of the encoding, not the encoding number"