# How to use Russian character json files (nlohmann json) in C++?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have this .json file:

```
{
  "name": [
    {
      "text": "Привет мир!"
    },
    {
      "text": "Hello World!"
    }
  ]
}
```

.
I want to read it, using nlohmann's json.cpp.
There is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "lib\include\nlohmann\json.hpp" 

using namespace std;
using namespace nlohmann;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); //The console method does not work
    json massive;
    string tempp;
    fstream f;
    f.open("json1.json");
    f >> massive;
    f.close();
    cout << massive["name"][0]["text"].dump()<<endl; //Russian text
    cout << massive["name"][1]["text"].dump(); //English text
}
```

. When I start the program, it outputs the following information:

```
"Р?С?РёР?РчС' Р?РёС?!"
"Hello World!"
```

English language works good, but Unknown characters appear instead of the text in Russian.
The json file encoding is utf-8.
How can I take information in Russian language from a json file

i tried "setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")"
Using temporary string variable can't solve problem

Solution to the problem:
Add to includes `#include <locale>` and `locale::global(std::locale{ ".UTF-8" });   cout.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.UTF-8"));` to int main()

Comment: `setlocale` is C-API and this code is C++. Also you've used invalid locale name (on any platform). What is your system and compiler?

Comment: The text is most likely UTF-8 encoded (two bytes per non-English character) but the console appears to interpret it as ANSI code page (each byte is treated as a separate character). The result is [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Try the trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45575863)

Comment: It is unlikely that the json library will do the transcoding from utf-8 to koi8-r (I believe) automatically, depending on the global C locale. Your code will get utf-8, irrespective of the locale. It's on you to transcode it to another character set.

Comment: he didn't set global c++ locale: `std::locale::global` so if library do any conversion it will be to C locale ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows and MSVC (you've used wrong slash in include directive) this should work:

```cpp
....
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale{".UTF-8"}); // inform standard library application logic uses UTF-8
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("")); // use system locale to select output encoding
....
```

Will fail on other systems since `".UTF-8"` is not valid locale name on this platforms.

Also please make sure that your input file is UTF-8 encoded (JSon should use only this encoding).

Note that there is no locale name `Russian`. On Windows valid locale name is for example: `ru_RU.UTF-8` `ru_RU.866`. For details see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings?view=msvc-170).