# How do I use the wmain() entry point in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, unicode, mingw, codeblocks, wmain

I did a fresh install of Code::Blocks (I installed [the one for Windows 7 which comes with GCC compiler](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries#windows) (codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe)). Then I tried to compile this very simple code:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I got this error message:

> c:\development\ide\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1......\libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c||
>   undefined reference to `WinMain@16'| ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0
>   warnings ===|

When I try to run my code with a `main()` entry, it runs as expected without any errors or warnings. How can I use `wmain()` in my code? What modifications do I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mingw does not fully support unicode. There is a wrapper available if you feel like trying it out. https://github.com/coderforlife/mingw-unicode-main

Answer (score 9):

The latest solution is to use the `-municode` option instead of the mingw-unicode-main wrapper.

For details, see:

- [wWinmain, Unicode, and Mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571250/wwinmain-unicode-and-mingw/11706847#11706847)

Comment: `mingw32-gcc-4.8.1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-municode'`

Comment: Note: `-municode` must be added to the *linker settings*.

Comment: I get the same error with the latest Code::Blocks (16.01) when adding `-municode` in the linker settings (linker is mingw32-g++.exe, and the MinGW directory also contains a mingw32-gcc-4.9.2.exe (which doesn't recognize the option either), but there's no mingw32-g++-4.9.2.exe)

Comment: @Medinoc: What nobody has bothered to tell us since 2012 is that there are two different compilers using the same name “MinGW”: [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) (integrated with Code::Blocks) and [MinGW-W64](https://mingw-w64.org/) (further split into [i686 and x86_64](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158244) variants). Confusingly, the latter is *not* a 64-bit version of the former. It’s just deceptive naming. Both are both 32 and 64-bit. And only the linker of the latter has the option `-municode`. Wasted a year of life – because people share advanced knowledge without basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Well mingw doesn't support wmain. And why would they. wide characters is a Microsoft Windows specific thing. On Windows You can use GetCommandLineW and CommandLineToArgV. On Linux I understand that Linux doesn't do encoding transformations on the command line arguments. And you can manually convert to UTF16LE by checking the current locale.