# Multibyte strings and ordinary string

Tags: c

I don't understand if for C every string is always a multibyte string meaning they are encoded as multibyte characters:

```
char s[] = "AAA"; 

char m[] = "X生";
```

is `s` also a multibyte string also if it doesn't contain a member of an extended character set like `m`?

I have this doubt because I read this from libc manuals:

> string” normally refers to multibyte character strings as opposed to
>   wide character strings. Wide character strings are arrays of type
>   wchar_t and as for multibyte character strings usually pointers of
>   type wchar_t * are used.

so I don't understand if **multibyte** is referred to the byte of the string (their number) of to the encode respect to wide character string.

Comment: `s` does not include multi-byte chars there (only ASCII chars which are each a single byte wide). But the string itself is four bytes long. Are you asking if all C strings are multiple bytes long, or if all chars are?

Comment: But encoded how? There are many ways to encode extended chars.

Comment: I edited the question. I Hope it's clearer.

Comment: The relevant keywords are translation character set, execution character set. This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872517/what-are-the-different-character-sets-used-for) seams to cover this topic properly.

Answer (score 3):

So the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (*C11 looks the same*) defines multibyte character as follows:

> sequence of one or more bytes representing a member of the extended character set of
>   either the source or the execution environment

So a *multibyte character* is part of the extended character set, so `s` is not made up of multi-byte characters.

*multibyte characters* are further defined in section `5.2.1.2`:

> The source character set may contain multibyte characters, used to
>   represent members of the extended character set. The execution
>   character set may also contain multibyte characters, which need not
>   have the same encoding as for the source character set. For both
>   character sets, the following shall hold:
>
> - The basic character set shall be present and each character shall be encoded as a single byte.
> - The presence, meaning, and representation of any additional members is locales pecific.
> - A multibyte character set may have a state-dependent encoding, wherein each sequence of multibyte characters begins in an initial
>     shift state and enters other locale-specific shift states when
>     specific multibyte characters are encountered in the sequence. While
>     in the initial shift state, all single-byte characters retain their
>     usual interpretation and do not alter the shift state. The
>     interpretation for subsequent bytes in the sequence is a function of
>     the current shift state.
> - A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character
>     independent of shift state. Such a byte shall not occur as part of any
>     other multibyte character.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily try to test how many bytes a string has. If I compile it on my machine with the following code:

```
char s[] = "AAA";
char m[] = "X生";
printf("s: %d\n", sizeof(s));
printf("m: %d\n", sizeof(m));
```

I'll get as an result the output

```
s: 4
m: 5
```

That means "s" isn't a multibyte string but "m" is. To make sure your compiler/system behaves the same way, I would just test it on your system.

Comment: It's the same on my system. However what I'd like to know is if for C, terminologically, both string are always multibyte string independently if they have a member not contained into a basic charset.