# Can't write chinese character into textfile with wofstream

Tags: c++, winapi, dev-c++, wofstream

I'm using `std::wofstream` to write characters in a text file.My characters can have chars from very different languages(english to chinese).
I want to print my `vector<wstring>` into that file.
If my vector contains only english characters I can print them without a problem.
But if I write chineses characters my file remains empty.

I browsed trough stackoverflow and all answers said bascially to use functions from the library:

```
#include <codecvt>
```

I can't include that library, because I am using Dev-C++ in version 5.11.
I did:`#define UNICODE` in all my header files.
I guess there is a really simple solution for that problem.
It would be great, if someone could help me out.

My code:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Path = "D:\\Users\\\t\\Desktop\\korrigiert_RotCommon_zh_check_error.log";
    wofstream Out;
    wstring eng = L"hello";
    wstring chi = L"程序";

    Out.open(Path, ios::out);

    //works.
    Out << eng;

    //fails
    Out << chi;

    Out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: You should probably add some code to show what you are doing.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without knowing what you do it's impossible for us to help you.

Comment: Despite the edit, this is still not considered a [mcve]. There is too much stuff here that is irrelevant to the question, e. g. the strings being stored in a vector, the nested loops and so on. Try to create a new application from scratch that showcases your problem with a minimum amount of code. This will greatly improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: `UNICODE` selects the version of Windows API calls. It's the `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbol that applies to the C Runtime. But since you aren't using any of the generic-text mappings anyway, neither symbol is required. That said, have you verified, that `chi` actually holds the characters you expect? Probably related, if not a duplicate: [What are the different character sets used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27872517/1889329).

Comment: Yes. I've verified it. I can use chinese characters in my programm. I can even write them into excel using a COM-Objet. I just can't print them into a normal text file.

Comment: By *"verification"* I meant looking at the raw bytes in memory, and comparing them against the expected UTF-16 encoding. Transferring them into a program that does who-knows-what to account for common programming errors is not helpful. Also, how do you determine, that your text file is wrong? Again, load it up in a hex editor and examine the raw bytes. Do they match the expected UTF-16 sequence?

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: You should probably show the code that detects the Chinese output failing.  For me, `Out << chi` succeeds, but it's the subsequent `Out << std::flush` (that you didn't write, but is implicit in the `close()`) that sets `std::ios_base::badbit` on the stream.

Comment: My file only contains "hello" if I execute my program.

Comment: @TobySpeight I didn't do that in my main programm. I just tried to fullfill what @ Some programmer dude wrote

Comment: Regarding the lack of <codecvt>. It's 2018 now, and that is a C++11 component. If your dev-c++ setup does not have that, it is only good for computer archeology, not for C++ programming.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the name of the `wofstream` implies it's a wide char stream, it's not. It's still a `char` stream that uses a convert facet from a locale to convert the `wchars` to `char`.

Here is what cppreference says:

> All file I/O operations performed through `std::basic_fstream<CharT>` use the `std::codecvt<CharT, char, std::mbstate_t>` facet of the locale imbued in the stream.

So you could either set the global locale to one that supports Chinese or `imbue` the stream. In both cases you'll get a single byte stream.

```
#include <locale>
//...
const std::locale loc = std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);

Out.open(Path, ios::out);
Out.imbue(loc);
```

Unfortunately `std::codecvt_utf8` is already deprecated[[2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html)]. This MSDN
magazine
article explains how to do UTF-8 conversion using `MultiByteToWideChar` [C++ - Unicode Encoding Conversions with STL Strings and Win32 APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763237.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Here the [Microsoft/vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/commit/ca692e52cee55da2f9d65d66e5f3997f3a335743) variant of an `to_utf8` conversion:

```
std::string to_utf8(const CWStringView w)
{
    const size_t size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, w.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    std::string output;
    output.resize(size - 1);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, w.c_str(), -1, output.data(), size - 1, nullptr, nullptr);
    return output;
 }
```

On the other side you can use normal binary stream and write the `wstring` data with `write()`.

```
std::ofstream Out(Path, ios::out | ios::binary);

const uint16_t bom = 0xFEFF;
Out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bom), sizeof(bom));    // optional Byte order mark

Out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(chi.data()), chi.size() * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: I can't include <codevct>, because my IDE is Dev-C++ 5.11. codevct seem to be an only MS VS option.

Comment: The function .imbue() give me a runtime error as I mentioned to Toby Speight

Comment: _"Unfortunately std::codecvt_utf8 is already deprecated[2]"_ -- from that link: _" this library component should be retired to Annex D, along side , until a suitable replacement is standardized"_ -- until there is any such replacement in sight I see no reason to stop using `std::codecvt_utf8`.

Comment: +1 for the 0xFEFF BOM adding... it's much more convenient than using WideCharToMultiByte. Not sure fully of the implications but it works...

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to tell your stream what locale to use:

```
Out.imbue(std::locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));
```

You'll obviously need to include `<locale>` for this.

Comment: When i copy that into my program, I'll get a crash at this line.
Its a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error. It says "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unsual way"

Comment: UTF-8 locales are not supported by MS C++ runtime.

Comment: I don't know the Microsoft runtime, but you'll probably have to adapt how you construct the locale to suit its way of writing locale strings.  I tested this on a Debian system (with the appropriate locale installed) and that changed your code from non-working to working.

Comment: @zett42, James McNellis: "No, UTF-8 locales are not supported." - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/10/the-great-c-runtime-crt-refactoring/