# How to display UTF-16 const strings if the source code is UTF-8 encoded in win32?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw, encode

My program need to display some unicode strings.  If I save the source code using UTF-16LE, everything works fine.  However, I was not be able to cross compile in linux using mingw.  If I save the source using UTF-8, the source code can be compiled with no problem.  But all the const unicode strings were not displayed correctly since they are encoded as UTF-8.  How can I properly display unicode string when the source code is saved as UTF-8 encoded?

**Example Code:**

```c
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"你好", L"你好", MB_OK);
}
```

[Compiled with UTF-16LE source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhYsQ.png)

[Compiled with UTF-8 source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYVp.png)

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, including the strings themselves and how you use them.

Comment: I imagine that `gcc` expects the file's encoding to match the terminal's encoding. In Windows, you can change the encoding of the terminal (console) using `chcp`. Specifically, `chcp 65001` is UTF-8.

Comment: Even if you use wide-character strings in the source, the editor might save the contents of the literals in UTF-8 or any other encoding possible. You might want to check your editor settings.

Comment: Use `u8"xxxxx"` for a UTF-8 encoded string literal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, the problem exists when I encode the source file to UTF-8.

Comment: Related, possibly even a duplicate of [What are the different character sets used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27872517/1889329).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it turns out visual studio cannot encode string correctly if the file is encoded to UTF-8 without signature(BOM).  Everything works fine after changing encoding scheme to UTF-8 with signature.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. It merely makes the undesired effects go away. The *real* issue is, that your *source code* fails to subscribe to any particular character encoding.

Comment: If this solution does work for you, please feel free to mark yourself.