# Flow of raw bytes of string literal into/out of the Windows (non-wide) execution character set at compile/runtime, & ANSI code pages vs. UTF-8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

I would like confirmation regarding my understanding of raw string literals and the (non-wide) `execution character set` on Windows.

**Relevant paragraphs for which I desire specific confirmation are in BOLD.**  But first, some background.

---

*BACKGROUND*

(relevant questions are in the paragraphs below in **bold**)

As a result of the helpful discussion beneath [@TheUndeadFish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871269/368896) to [this question that I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871124/does-the-multibyte-to-wide-string-conversion-function-mbstowcs-when-passed-a), I have attempted to understand the rules determining the *character set* and *encoding* used as the `execution character set` in MSVC on Windows (in the C++ specification sense of `execution character set`; see [@DietmarKühl's posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872517/what-are-the-different-character-sets-used-for)).

*I suspect that some might consider it a waste of time to even bother trying to understand the ANSI-related behavior of `char *` (i.e., non-wide) strings for non-ASCII characters in MSVC.*

For example, consider [@IInspectable's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27871124/368896):

> You cannot throw a UTF-8 encoded string at the ANSI version of a
>   Windows API and hope for anything sane to happen.

Please note that in my current i18n project on a Windows MFC-based application, I will be *removing* all calls to the non-wide (i.e., ANSI) versions of API calls, and I expect the compiler to generate **`execution wide-character set`** strings, *NOT* `execution character set` (non-wide) strings internally.

However, I want to *understand* the existing code, which already has some internationalization that uses the ANSI API functions.  *Even if some consider the behavior of the ANSI API on non-ASCII strings to be insane, I want to understand it.*

I think like others, I have found it difficult to locate clarified documentation about the non-wide `execution character set` on Windows.

In particular, because the (non-wide) `execution character set` is defined by the C++ standard to be a sequence of `char` (as opposed to `wchar_t`), UTF-16 cannot be used internally to store characters in the non-wide `execution character set`.  In this day and age, it makes sense that the Unicode character set, encoded via UTF-8 (a `char`-based encoding), would therefore be used as the character set and encoding of the `execution character set`.  To my understanding, this is the case on Linux.  However, sadly, this is **not** the case on Windows - even MSVC 2013.

This leads to the first of my two questions.

---

*Question #1*: Please confirm that I'm correct in the following paragraph.

With this background, here's my question.  **In MSVC, including VS 2013, it seems that the `execution character set` is one of the (many possible) ANSI character sets, using one of the (many possible) *code pages* corresponding to that particular given ANSI character set to define the encoding - rather than the Unicode character set with UTF-8 encoding.**  (Note that I am asking about the NON-WIDE `execution character set`.)  Is this correct?

---

*BACKGROUND, CONTINUED* (assuming I'm correct in Question #1)

If I understand things correctly, than the above bolded paragraph is arguably a large part of the cause of the "insanity" of using the ANSI API on Windows.

Specifically, consider the "sane" case - in which Unicode and UTF-8 are used as the `execution character set`.

In this case, it does not matter what machine the code is compiled on, or when, and it does not matter what machine the code runs on, or when.  The actual raw bytes of a string literal will always be internally represented in the Unicode character set with UTF-8 as the encoding, and the runtime system will always treat such strings, semantically, as UTF-8.

No such luck in the "insane" case (if I understand correctly), in which ANSI character sets and code page encodings are used as the `execution character set`.  In this case (the Windows world), the runtime behavior may be **affected** by the machine that the code is compiled on, in comparison with the machine the code runs on.

---

*Here, then, is Question #2*: Again, please confirm that I'm correct in the following paragraph.

With this continued background in mind, I suspect that: **Specifically, with MSVC, the `execution character set` and its encoding depends in some not-so-easy-to-understand way on the locale selected by the *compiler* on the machine the compiler is running on, at the time of compilation.  This will determine the raw bytes for character literals that are 'burned into' the executable.  And, at run-time, the MSVC C runtime library may be using a *different* `execution character set` and encoding to *interpret* the raw bytes of character literals that were burned into the executable.** Am I correct?

(I may add examples into this question at some point.)

---

*FINAL COMMENTS*

Fundamentally, if I understand correctly, the above bolded paragraph explains the "insanity" of using the ANSI API on Windows.  Due to the possible difference between the ANSI character set and encoding chosen by the *compiler* and the ANSI character set and encoding chosen by the C runtime, non-ASCII characters in string literals may not appear as expected in a running MSVC program when the ANSI API is used in the program.

(Note that the ANSI "insanity" really only applies to string literals, because according to the C++ standard the actual source code must be written in a subset of ASCII (and source code comments are discarded by the compiler).)

The description above is the best current understanding I have of the ANSI API on Windows in regards to string literals.  I would like confirmation that my explanation is well-formed and that my understanding is correct.

Comment: TL;DR...I have a feeling this belongs on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You might be interested in reading http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @MarkTolonen - Thanks! I've read it about 100 times, and in fact I'll be using the approach of utf8everywhere.org to implement my internationalization.  Note that utf8everywhere.org recommends using the wide versions of API calls, which I'll be doing (converting to/from UTF-8 only at the point of use).  However, the *existing* application I'm working with uses some *narrow* API's for some (weak) i18n, and I would (nonetheless) like to understand the non-wide issues.

Comment: Note 1: Windows generally has *two* non-Unicode characters sets, one for windowed apps and a different one for console apps in a command window. Note 2: Windows *never* uses UTF-8 on its own, you need to go out of your way to configure it and the support is reportedly buggy.

Comment: @Mark: Considering that the entire metadata stored in .NET assemblies is encoded using UTF-8, I'd be somewhat surprised to hear that Windows' UTF-8 support is buggy.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The support isn't so much buggy as limited. In particular, `MultiByteToUnicode` will happily take multi-byte UTF-8 and translate it to UTF-16. I believe it even supports characters outside the BMP. However, all the *A equivalents to the native *W functions don't do this. It's documented, so not really a bug.

Comment: Just for reference, the reason Windows and Visual Studio don't use UTF-8 as the execution character set is that they were both written before UTF-8 was invented.  Backwards compatibility requirements have locked that limitation in.

Comment: @MSalters: I guess that when Mark mentions buggy UTF-8 support he is probably thinking of the console.  It nominally supports a UTF-8 code page but this mode, if not buggy, is at least unexpectedly difficult to work with.  (I've seen more than a few questions about it, and the answers usually left me confused.  I've never tried to use it myself.)

Answer (score 0):

A very long story, and I have problems finding a single clear question. However, I think I can resolve a number of misunderstandings that led to this.

First of, "ANSI" is a synonym for the (narrow) execution character set. UTF-16 is the execution wide-character set.

The compiler will NOT choose for you. If you use narrow `char` strings, they are ANSI as far as the compiler (runtime) is aware.

Yes, the particular "ANSI" character encoding can matter. If you compile a `L"ä"` literal on your PC, and your source code is in CP1252, then that `ä` character is compiled to a UTF-16 `ä`.  However, the same byte could be another non-ASCII character in other encodigns, which would result in a different UTF-16 character.

Note however that MSVC **is** perfectly capable of compiling both UTF-8 and UTF-16 source code, as long as it starts with `U+FEFF` "BOM". This makes the whole theoretical problem pretty much a non-issue.

[edit]
"Specifically, with *MSVC*, the execution character set and its encoding depends..."

No, MSVC has nothing to do with the execution character set, really. The meaning of `char(0xE4)` is determined by the OS. To see this, check the MinGW compiler. Executables produced by MinGW behave the same as those of MSVC, as both target the same OS.

Comment: Thanks.  There are multiple possible ANSI character sets and character set encodings, correct?  Therefore, the question of the compile-time vs. runtime choice of `execution character set` for the non-wide API is relevant, I think.  (Referring to your answer, I'm interested in the case where the string literal is of type `char` - `"ä"` - rather than the case where it's of type `wchar_t` (`L"ä"`), as you've written.)

Comment: UTF-16 source files (both big endian and little endian) do not require a BOM. UTF-8 source files, however, do. See [Unicode Support in the Compiler and Linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2.aspx) for details.

Comment: @IInspectable: I guess that makes sense. The first two characters of a C++ file **must** be ASCII, so looking at the first bytes you can always tell if it's UTF-16 BE or LE.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: You have to understand that the result of the compiler is a **binary** file. It will NOT contain "ä". It might contain `0xE4`.

Comment: I am assuming that the binary file contains raw bytes representing character literals, and that these raw bytes exactly correspond to a particular encoding and character set.  Therefore, I do consider them to be a sequence of raw bytes (such as `0xE4`); but my question regarding the *character set* and corresponding *encoding* used to generate and interpret these raw bytes still applies, I think.  (Note that the raw bytes in the binary file correspond to the C++ `execution character set`, if my understanding is correct.)

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: how those raw bytes are interpreted depends on what you do with them.  If you pass them (as narrow strings) to the C runtime or to the Win32 API then by default the interpretation will depend on the user's internationalization settings.

Comment: Bringing up MinGW may be misleading, because it uses the C runtime that ships with Windows (which it shouldn't, but now's not the time) which is derived from Visual Studio.  So the two aren't entirely independent.  But I would imagine that most Windows compilers use the native character set.  (I wonder what Cygwin does?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks.  Exactly.  I attempted to focus my question on relevant C runtime library functions that would be passed these raw bytes, via the bolded paragraphs in my question; here's an excerpt: `And, at run-time, the MSVC C runtime library may be using a different execution character set and encoding to interpret the raw bytes of character literals`.  I think your comment helps answer my question - it seems the descriptive explanation in my question is (roughly) on the mark (at least, I hope so).  If you have time, you could expand your comments into an answer!  Thanks again.