# The code below prints the character for the pi number in VS2019, instead of the character `ã`. What am I missing?

Tags: c++, unicode

The code below prints the character for the pi number in VS2019, instead of the character `ã`.

```
#include<iostream>
const char* p = "\u00E3";           // Character ã LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE

int main() {
    std::cout << p << '\n';         // This should compile by any compiler supporting some ASCII compatible encoding.
                                    // It does compile in clang and GCC, printing `ã` in both. In VS2019 it prints the symbol for
                                    // the pi number. However if I debug the code I can see the character `ã` in
                                    // memory in the address given by `p`. What am I missing?
}
```

See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b6e99c586500395) in Coliru.

**Edit**

The question for which this is considered a duplicate doesn't use a universal-character-name as is the case in the above code. Therefore this should compile and execute correctly in VS2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Visual Studio character encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857668/c-visual-studio-character-encoding-issues)

Comment: @Botje See my edit above.

Comment: U+00E3 converted to UTF-8 is a pair of bytes `c3 a3`. Are you sure you're not seeing the cp1251 interpretation of a c3 byte  `Г     CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER GHE` ? In this case you need to switch your terminal and/or system encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Possibly a code page issue.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set

Comment: @Botje U+00E3 is already the Unicode code point for the character `ã`, as stated [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/full#nt:universal-character-name) in the most recent C++ draft.

Comment: @JohnKalane -- What is the code page of the terminal?  For code page 437, `e3` is a pi symbol.

Comment: @JohnKalane -- If you're using Windows, go back in your program editor, hold the Alt key down, and on the keypad enter `227`, which is `0xE3` in decimal.  Do you see the pi symbol show up?  If you do, then that gives you a clue as to what is occurring in the output.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I do see the pie symbol. I have no clue whatsoever.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There should be no issues with code pages as I said before, `\u00E3` is a universal-character-name for the character `ã`, unless there is a bug in VS2019. Also, I can see the character `ã` in the address `p` in memory when I debug the code in Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnKalane --  *There should be no issues with code pages as I said before* -- Well obviously there is an issue, as again `0xE3` is the pi symbol for codepage 437.  Coincidence?  -- *\u00E3 is a universal-character-name for the character ã* -- Unicode is not "universal" -- if the terminal doesn't support it or understand it, then it's up to you to figure out how to make your terminal support Unicode.  Unicode is a specification, not a mandate.

Comment: @JohnKalane Can you write that character to a file instead of the console? If it contains a single `e3` then C++ is doing its job and your console is to blame. That is why the answer I linked has references to `chcp` and `SetConsoleOutputCP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, U+00E3 is the code point for `ã`.  That is *just a number*.  That number has to be encoded to be stored anywhere (memory, a file, etc.).  You have an encoding issue.  You wrote the byte 0xe3 to the terminal but its code page is cp437, where 0xe3 is decoded as `π`.

On Windows, using wide strings and setting the terminal mode to UTF-16 will work.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const wchar_t* p = L"\u00E3"; // wide string

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); // set console mode
    std::wcout << p << '\n';
}
```

Output (compiled with VS2019 and run in Windows 10 console window):

```
ã
```

Note that the font the console uses has to support the characters printed, otherwise you get the replacement character U+FFFD `�` (look of this character will vary with font as well).