# Getting extra character with file name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, file-handling, cfilefind

I am using CFileFind to get files list . i have an issue with one particular file always. getting file title with extra character '?' appended .

original name  : _KO - Ennamo Yedho Video Song HD_test‏.txt

retrieved name : _KO - Ennamo Yedho Video Song HD_test?.txt

```
   CFileFind finder ;

    bool bWorking = finder.FindFile ("F:\\*.*")  ;



     while (bWorking)
     {
        bWorking = finder.FindNextFile ( ) ;
        CString file_lst  =finder.GetFileTitle()  ;
     }
```

I also check the same in command prompt.Same problem is happening . Someone Guide me where i am wrong .

[image]

[image]

Comment: The original file name contains some non-printing Unicode character. You need to work with wide (Unicode) strings, not ANSI strings, in your program.

Comment: Thanks will look into it , Meanwhile clarify why i get the same issue in cmd prompt also ? has cmd prompt not handled wide strings? check the link for the cmd prompt image .

Comment: No, by default the command prompt does not display Unicode. It uses the system ANSI/multi-byte character set.

Comment: But i am using multi byte character set programming how to get unicode
file name

Comment: Stop using the multi-byte character set and use Unicode. It's pretty simple. There's no need for anything but Unicode anymore.

Comment: I am using GetWindowTextW to get the correct file name. not change the project settings. Any way thanks for your helping @CodyGray .

Comment: Okay, so you are using the correct function. The problem is that you're trying to display the string in the command prompt window, which doesn't support Unicode properly without [some cajoling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826188/what-most-correct-way-to-set-the-encoding-in-c/15845530#15845530). For a quick test, try displaying the result of `GetWindowTextW` in a `MessageBoxW`.