# Input encoding issue in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am developing a simple `console` application with Visual Studio 2013

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    std::wstring name;
    std::wcout << L"Enter your name: ";
    std::wcin >> name;
    std::wcout << L"Hello, " << name << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter as input `Ángel` the application works well and the output is

```
Hello, Ángel
```

the problem is that If i put a breakpoint on

```
std::wcout << L"Hello, " << name << std::endl;
```

the Visual studio debugger shows

```
+       name    L"µngel"    std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >
```

Although the output in console is correct in other part of the program I have a call to `win32api` function `CopyFileW()` and it always fails because the path has the **substring** `Ángel` and the **substring** passed to function is transformed to `µngel`

Comment: I think you need to change the codification of the source file, something like utf-16 I think.

Comment: The issue is that the command prompt uses a different encoding than the Win32 APIs. Does the answer to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826188/what-most-correct-way-to-set-the-encoding-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Windows consoles are broken by default.

The problem arises from Windows using a different 8-bit codepage in console application than in Windows applications. By default, in Western Windows versions, the default 8-bit codepage (called ANSI) is Windows-1252, while the console 8-bit codepage (called OEM) is CP850.

Since your program doesn't know if it is reading from console or from a redirected file, it simply assumes ANSI input. But when you type `Á`, it is actually the codepoint from [CP850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850): `0xB5`. It is then interpreted using [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as `µ`, that is Unicode characters U+00B5. The funny thing is that when you print it into the console, the inverse transformation happens, and you see a `Á` again. Two wrongs make one right!

But when you want to use that characters in a non-console context, it is actually a `µ`.

You may think that you can convert from OEM to ANSI and then from ANSI to Unicode, and that would seem to work... until you run your program as:

```
c:\> myprogram < input.txt
```

And you wrote that `input.txt` using notepad, so it is using ANSI, and then you are doing a conversion you do not need.

You say then that you could detect if you are reading the actual console or a redirection and do the OEM to ANSI conversion only when there is no redirect... until you do:

```
c:\> echo Ángel | myprogram
```

And you are doing it wrong again!

There are a lot of alternatives, but none of them works completely fine. At least you should use a Unicode font and then a more *normal* codepage. Something like `chcp 1252` to change the OEM codepage to match the ANSI one. You can even configure it by default with a bit of registry foo:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP=1252
```