# C ++ print → on windows console

Tags: c++, printing, symbols

I use visual studio 2012 and i would like an easy way to print out → on windows console using
     cout.
if it's not possible with cout then something else.

Comment: Personaly, I'd just settle for `cout << "-->";` :)

Comment: yeah but what if i want ↓

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the Wide-Character version of `cout`, which is called `wcout`. It can print wide character strings, but you must put `L` before the string to declare it wide character.
[MSDN Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sda3xxca%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

```
std::wcout << L"→";
```

Comment: Hah, it gets separated on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=eb1b973d58b466469ce3907a6124e842-1dfa45f65786f4a26064bc85b3de325a) :p

Comment: all i get is nothing, not even a space

Comment: @Kostas, It works fine, it's just the console's inability to display it. Put it in a call to `MessageBoxW` and watch it magically work there.

Comment: can you write exactly the part where i use messageboxw because i have no idea how to...

Comment: @Kostas, There are tons of examples. And it's probably not what you want, it was just to show you that the code works when displayed by something that can handle these characters.

Comment: @Kostas: (1) `#include <windows.h>`. (2) `MessageBoxW (NULL, L"→↓", L"...", MB_OK);`.

Comment: ah i see now what message box is, though i would like a way for it to work on the console :/

Comment: @Kostas: You might want to read this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371012/how-do-i-print-utf-8-from-c-console-application-on-windows , but keep in mind that UTF-8 is different from the kind of Unicode characters that `L"whatever"` gives you.