# the problem with translation using gettext technology

Tags: c, gettext

While doing coursework at the university, I had a task to output the entered number in text format and translate this program using gettext technology. Everything is compiled, but the program outputs the tap response incorrectly.

[image]

Using Windows 11, VS.
The code is presented below

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define ENABLE_NLS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAX_LEN_STRING_NUMBER 6
#define _(String) gettext(String)
#define PACKAGE "kursovaya"
#define LOCALEDIR "locale"


struct numbers
{
    char num[30];
};

struct declensions
{
    char numDeclensions[30];
};

struct words
{
    char word[30];
};

struct numbersFromTenToNineteen
{
    char numNumbersFromTenToNineteen[30];
};

struct rubel
{
    char rub[30];
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("kursovaya", "locale");
    //bind_textdomain_codeset(PACKAGE, "CP1251");
    textdomain("kursovaya");
    size_t endInputNunber;
    struct numbers num[] = { {""}, {_("one ")}, {_("two ")}, {_("three ")}, {_("four ")}, {_("five ")}, {_("six ")}, {_("seven ")}, {_("eight ")}, {_("nine ")} };
    struct words word[] = { {_("thousands ")}, {_("hundreds ")}, {_("dozens ")} };
    struct declensions numDeclensions[] = { {""}, {""}, {_("twenty ")}, {_("thirty ")}, {_("forty ")}, {_("fifty ")}, {_("sixty ")}, {_("seventy ")}, {_("eighty ")}, {_("ninety ")} };
    struct numbersFromTenToNineteen numNumbersFromTenToNineteen[] = { {_("ten")}, {_("eleven")}, {_("twelve")}, {_("thirteen")}, {_("fourteen")}, {_("fifteen")}, {_("sixteen")}, {_("seventeen")}, {_("eighteen")}, {_("nineteen")} };
    struct rubel rub[] = { {_("rubel ")}, {_("rubels ")}, {_("rurubels")} };
    char inputNumber[MAX_LEN_STRING_NUMBER] = { '\0' };
    char outputStringNumber[300];
    char variableJinFor;
    char variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen;
    int lenInputNumber = 0;
    int digitOfTheNumber;
    int workWhile = 20;
    int next;

    outputStringNumber[0] = '\0';

    while (1)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &next);
        while ((getchar()) != '\n');

        system("cls");

        switch (next)
        {
        case 1:
            puts(_("enter a number from 0 to 9999"));
            fgets(inputNumber, MAX_LEN_STRING_NUMBER, stdin);

            endInputNunber = strlen(inputNumber);
            if (inputNumber[endInputNunber - 1] == '\n')
                inputNumber[endInputNunber - 1] = '\0';

            for (int i = 0; i < endInputNunber; i++)
                if (inputNumber[i] != '\0')
                    lenInputNumber++;

            digitOfTheNumber = lenInputNumber;

            while (digitOfTheNumber > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < lenInputNumber; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        variableJinFor = j + '0';
                        if (inputNumber[i] == variableJinFor)
                        {
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 4)
                            {
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, word[i].word);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 3)
                            {
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, word[1].word);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 2)
                            {
                                if (inputNumber[0] == '1' && lenInputNumber < 3)
                                {
                                    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
                                    {
                                        variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen = n + '0';
                                        if (inputNumber[1] == variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen)
                                            strcat(outputStringNumber, numNumbersFromTenToNineteen[n].numNumbersFromTenToNineteen);
                                    }
                                    digitOfTheNumber = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                    strcat(outputStringNumber, numDeclensions[j].numDeclensions);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 1)
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                            if (inputNumber[0] == '0')
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, _("zero"));
                        }
                    }
                    digitOfTheNumber--;
                }
            if (inputNumber[endInputNunber] == '1' || inputNumber[endInputNunber] == '0')
                strcat(outputStringNumber, rub[0].rub);
            else
                strcat(outputStringNumber, rub[1].rub);
            
            puts(outputStringNumber);

            printf("%s", num[1].num);

            puts(_("press any key to continue"));
            getchar();
            break;
        case 2:
            //fgets(inputNumber, MAX_LEN_STRING_NUMBER, mass); /*это так не работает*/

            endInputNunber = strlen(inputNumber);
            if (inputNumber[endInputNunber - 1] == '\n')
                inputNumber[endInputNunber - 1] = '\0';

            for (int i = 0; i < endInputNunber; i++)
                if (inputNumber[i] != '\0')
                    lenInputNumber++;

            digitOfTheNumber = lenInputNumber;

            while (digitOfTheNumber > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < lenInputNumber; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        variableJinFor = j + '0';
                        if (inputNumber[i] == variableJinFor)
                        {
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 4)
                            {
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, word[i].word);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 3)
                            {
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, word[1].word);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 2)
                            {
                                if (inputNumber[0] == '1' && lenInputNumber < 3)
                                {
                                    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
                                    {
                                        variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen = n + '0';
                                        if (inputNumber[1] == variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen)
                                            strcat(outputStringNumber, numNumbersFromTenToNineteen[n].numNumbersFromTenToNineteen);
                                    }
                                    digitOfTheNumber = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                    strcat(outputStringNumber, numDeclensions[j].numDeclensions);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 1)
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                            if (inputNumber[0] == '0')
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, _("zero"));
                        }
                    }
                    digitOfTheNumber--;
                }
            if (inputNumber[endInputNunber] == '1' || inputNumber[endInputNunber] == '0')
                strcat(outputStringNumber, rub[0].rub);
            else
                strcat(outputStringNumber, rub[1].rub);
            puts(outputStringNumber);

            puts(_("press any key to continue"));
            getchar();
            break;
        case 3:
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Internet searches and questions to the neural network were unsuccessful. there were attempts to change the encoding, but they didn't help either

I present the minimum working code that works in English

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define ENABLE_NLS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAX_LEN_STRING_NUMBER 6
#define _(String) gettext(String)
#define PACKAGE "kursovaya"
#define LOCALEDIR "locale"


struct numbers
{
    char num[30];
};

struct declensions
{
    char numDeclensions[30];
};

struct words
{
    char word[30];
};

struct numbersFromTenToNineteen
{
    char numNumbersFromTenToNineteen[30];
};

struct rubel
{
    char rub[30];
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("kursovaya", "locale");
    
    textdomain("kursovaya");
    //bind_textdomain_codeset("kursovaya", "UTF-8");
    size_t endInputNunber;
    struct numbers num[] = { {""}, {_("one ")}, {_("two ")}, {_("three ")}, {_("four ")}, {_("five ")}, {_("six ")}, {_("seven ")}, {_("eight ")}, {_("nine ")} };
    struct words word[] = { {_("thousands ")}, {_("hundreds ")}, {_("dozens ")} };
    struct declensions numDeclensions[] = { {""}, {""}, {_("twenty ")}, {_("thirty ")}, {_("forty ")}, {_("fifty ")}, {_("sixty ")}, {_("seventy ")}, {_("eighty ")}, {_("ninety ")} };
    struct numbersFromTenToNineteen numNumbersFromTenToNineteen[] = { {_("ten")}, {_("eleven")}, {_("twelve")}, {_("thirteen")}, {_("fourteen")}, {_("fifteen")}, {_("sixteen")}, {_("seventeen")}, {_("eighteen")}, {_("nineteen")} };
    struct rubel rub[] = { {_("rubel ")}, {_("rubels ")}, {_("rurubels")} };
    char inputNumber[MAX_LEN_STRING_NUMBER] = { '\0' };
    char outputStringNumber[300];
    char variableJinFor;
    char variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen;
    int lenInputNumber = 0;
    int digitOfTheNumber;
    int workWhile = 20;
    int next;

    outputStringNumber[0] = '\0';


    while (1)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &next);
        while ((getchar()) != '\n');

        system("cls");

        switch (next)
        {
        case 1:
            puts(_("enter a number from 0 to 9999"));
            fgets(inputNumber, MAX_LEN_STRING_NUMBER, stdin);

            endInputNunber = strlen(inputNumber);
            if (inputNumber[endInputNunber - 1] == '\n')
                inputNumber[endInputNunber - 1] = '\0';

            for (int i = 0; i < endInputNunber; i++)
                if (inputNumber[i] != '\0')
                    lenInputNumber++;

            digitOfTheNumber = lenInputNumber;

            while (digitOfTheNumber > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < lenInputNumber; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        variableJinFor = j + '0';
                        if (inputNumber[i] == variableJinFor)
                        {
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 4)
                            {
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, word[i].word);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 3)
                            {
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, word[1].word);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 2)
                            {
                                if (inputNumber[0] == '1' && lenInputNumber < 3)
                                {
                                    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
                                    {
                                        variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen = n + '0';
                                        if (inputNumber[1] == variableJinForNumbersFromTenToNineteen)
                                            strcat(outputStringNumber, numNumbersFromTenToNineteen[n].numNumbersFromTenToNineteen);
                                    }
                                    digitOfTheNumber = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                    strcat(outputStringNumber, numDeclensions[j].numDeclensions);
                            }
                            if (digitOfTheNumber == 1)
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, num[j].num);
                            if (inputNumber[0] == '0')
                                strcat(outputStringNumber, _("zero"));
                        }
                    }
                    digitOfTheNumber--;
                }
            if (inputNumber[endInputNunber] == '1' || inputNumber[endInputNunber] == '0')
                strcat(outputStringNumber, rub[0].rub);
            else
                strcat(outputStringNumber, rub[1].rub);
            
            puts(outputStringNumber);

            printf("%s", num[1].num);

            puts(_("press any key to continue"));
            getchar();
```

Comment: What is your character-encoding?

Comment: Aside: you seem to be guessing that `char outputStringNumber[300];` is a large enough buffer for all the `strcat()` operations.

Comment: Another aside: instead of the bizarre code to find the string length after [removing a trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221) you could use `lenInputNumber = strlen(inputNumber);`. And I wonder why in `case 2:` you commented out the `fgets()` line but proceeded to work with its supposed input.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], there's way too much code here. That also helps finding the mistake yourself, which is why it's required. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print UTF-8 from c++ console application on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371012/how-do-i-print-utf-8-from-c-console-application-on-windows)